# Set a SeekBarPreference in the preferencemenu and not using dialog

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, seekbar

I'm creating preference menu and trying to show the seekbar in the preference menu and not by showing a dialogbox.

Do I have to make it through a new xml layout file and new Preference class?
It's seems so much work in contrast to make a Dialog SeekBarPreference.

Any comments, tips, code snips or lenks would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly? Is something like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
The PreferenceActivity extends from the ListActivity, so the preference is essentially a listview. You can achieve this feature this way:

1. Create a PreferenceActivity and in the onCreate() method:

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);

   ```
   }
   ```

   2. In the "main" Layout, make sure there is a ListView, so that the your preference.xml
      file will be linked to that ListView. Declare it this way:

   ```
   <ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

   <SeekBar
       android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```

Note the id for the ListView must be:`@android:id/list`

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I'm trying to make.